# Git move files from 1 branch to another

Tags: git, git-flow

I am working with git using git-flow.

I was working in the `branchA`, I modified some file, but these files were supposed to be modified in a branch of a new feature that I haven't created  yet. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide the commands you entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, you can soft reset the commit you did to the invalid branch, then stash the changes you introduced and execute

```
git stash branch feature/<wahetever>
```

This way, through stash you can move the changes. Another way is to start new feature branch and with `cherry-pick` move the commits that should be in the new branch.